# What would $Cov(2X, 4X + 3Y)$ be?

Tags: probability, covariance

Since, $Cov(X, X + 3Y) = Cov(X, X) + 3Cov(X, Y) = V(X)  + 3 Cov(X, Y)$

What would $Cov(2X, 4X + 3Y)$  be?

Comment: Hint: covariance is (kinda sorta) bilinear.

Comment: Use the definition of covariance, even if you don't know it is bilinear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

$$Cov(2X, 4X + 3Y) = 2Cov(X,4X+3Y) = 2Cov(X,4X) + 2Cov(X,3Y) \\ = 8Cov(X,X) + 6Cov(X,Y) = 8V(X)+6Cov(X,Y) \; .$$